# GitHub > Linking Issues to a Release

Tags: github, github-api

I'm currently using GitHub Milestones, to track Issues that I want included in a Release...

Now, that I want to push a new Release, I can't see anyway of linking Issues to a Release (or for that matter, Milestones to a Release).

I was expecting that I could use the GitHub's Releases as a Changelog, so that users could easily see what Issues/Enhancements were fixed/included in a release.

e.g. `Version-1.123` contained fixes for Issues `#111`, `#222` and `#333`.

Does this functionality exist?

**N.B.**

- I couldn't find anything under the [GitHub Developer API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/)
- Also, this is [the first Release](https://github.com/jenkinsci/groovy-events-listener-plugin/releases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have [markdown](https://api.github.com/repos/asizikov/AsyncSuffix/releases/2324370) in the `body` field of the request.

```
    POST /repos/:owner/:repo/releases
    {
       "tag_name": "v1.0.0",
       "target_commitish": "master",
       "name": "v1.0.0",
       "body": "* Fixed #1 \r\n * Fixed #2 ",
       "draft": false,
       "prerelease": false
    }
```

Will look like:

[image]

I guess that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know... I could manually add the Issues in the description, but I was hoping that this would be available out of the box. What if there was hundreds of issues?

Comment: You can give a link to milestone

Comment: I mean there is nothing out of the box, and I can imagine why.  It's hard to come up with a generic way, everybody is using release notes in their own way.

Comment: It's available now. There's an endpoint that does it, but you can also script the GitHub CLI (gh) to generate notes for you that calls that endpoint. GitHub Actions hosted runners have gh installed, so just run `gh release create --generate-notes ...`